# Form prints multiple times when more than one record is pulled in sub report 2

Tags: crystal-reports

In Crystal reports I am making a summary statement and I got all of it but 2 parts are giving me trouble... I have two sections that needed to be totaled so I made subreports and put them in detail a and detail b.  Each section potentially can have multiple sections or no sections.  whenever there is more than one line in detail b or sub report 2 it prints the whole report that many times.  So if there is only one record in Detail B it prints like
header a
detail a
footer a
header b
detail b
footer b
But if there is 2 records in detail b it prints
header a
detail a
footer a
header b
detail b
footer b
header a
detail a
footer a
header b
detail b
footer b
And the pattern continues if there is 3 records in detail b.

I also need to subtract the total of detail b from detail a.  I can grab the number i need from detail b but whenever i try to get the total from detail a it comes back as a 0 instead of the number.  Please Help me!  Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

review your links or create a group on your subreport, so it won't show same info 2ice. Take in consideration that if you are using shared or global variables to show totals from your subreport, it should be place in a different section of your subreport. For example:

If your subreport is on `Details Section A`, you should place your variable in `Section B`.

try placing those subreports in your report header rather than your details. Create another 2 RH sections and place them on it

Comment: I figured out the total one.  But I currently do have a group within subreport b and have it so it will not print duplicates. Is there a way in the main report to suppress if duplicate on a subreport?

Comment: could you please update your original post with images of your report in design and preview views, so we can help you with that.

Comment: Is that what you were looking for or do you need me to add anything else?

Comment: It only reprints if there are multiple lines in the credit memos section if there are multiple records in the invoices it prints just fine. And it prints the same amount of times as lines in the credit section

Comment: could you tried placing those subreports in your report header rather than your details. Create another 2 RH sections and place them on it.